# Filling in array of objects in form

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular-ngmodel, angular-reactive-forms

I have a function that gets called on click and I have an array of objects that I am trying to pass to my form.

```
[{baseline: true, order: 0, query: "string", sourceId: "string", sourcePath: "string", sourceType:'value1'}, {baseline: false, order: 1, query: "string", sourceId: "string", sourcePath: "string", sourceType:'value2'},{baseline: false, order: 1, query: "string", sourceId: "string", sourcePath: "string", sourceType:'value2'}]
```

my function is as below:

```
pipelines = [];
constructor( private _fb: FormBuilder) {
this.newForm = _fb.group({
   query:'',
   sourceId:'',
   sourcePath:'',
   sourceType: ''
   });
}


getFormgroup(name): boolean {
let val = name;
let index = this.getdata.findIndex(obj => obj.configName === val);
console.log(this.getdata[index]['sources']);
this.pipelines = this.getdata[index]['sources'];
console.log(this.pipelines);
return true;
```

}

```
   a (click)="getFormgroup(mem.configName) ? addtionalInfo = true  addtionalInfo = false" class="clickable">{{mem.configName}}</a>
    <form [formGroup] ="newForm">
             <div *ngFor="let pipes of pipelines; let i=index;">
    <select name = "sourceType" formControlName="sourceType [(ngModel)]="pipes[i].sourceType">
       <option disabled selected value="">Select Source Type</option>
       <option value="value1">value1</option>
       <option value="value2">value2</option>
       <option value="value3">value3</option>
   </select>
     <input name = "sourceId" formControlName="sourceId" [(ngModel)]="pipes[i].sourceId" type="text">

    <input name="sourcePath" formControlName="sourcePath" [(ngModel)]="pipes[i].sourcePath">

    <textarea name="query" formControlName="query" [(ngModel)]="pipes[i].query">{{query}}</textarea>

    </div>
    </form>
```

So basically I am storing array of objects in `pipelines` and when the function is called, I try to loop over pipelines and display the values in the dropdown and textboxes.
However, I get `Cannot read property 'sourceType' of undefined` error and the boxes are empty without any values filled.

Comment: Why are you doing `pipes[i]`? `i` is your index for your `pipelines` array and `pipes` is the current object at that index.

Comment: Oh. Yes. Such a silly mistake.